# WordPress: register_settings helper

Tags: wordpress

Im trying to make register_settings a little bit cleaner for my plugin.
Now it looks this way:

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'hpblogposts_register_settings' );
function hpblogposts_register_settings() {
    register_setting( 'hpblogposts_settings_options_group', 'linkid01' );
    register_setting( 'hpblogposts_settings_options_group', 'linktext01' );
    register_setting( 'hpblogposts_settings_options_group', 'linkalt01' );
    register_setting( 'hpblogposts_settings_options_group', 'linkid02' );
    register_setting( 'hpblogposts_settings_options_group', 'linktext02' );
    register_setting( 'hpblogposts_settings_options_group', 'linkalt02' );
    register_setting( 'hpblogposts_settings_options_group', 'linkid03' );
    register_setting( 'hpblogposts_settings_options_group', 'linktext03' );
    register_setting( 'hpblogposts_settings_options_group', 'linkalt03' );
    register_setting( 'hpblogposts_settings_options_group', 'linkid04' );
    register_setting( 'hpblogposts_settings_options_group', 'linktext04' );
    register_setting( 'hpblogposts_settings_options_group', 'linkalt04' );
    register_setting( 'hpblogposts_settings_options_group', 'linkid05' );
    register_setting( 'hpblogposts_settings_options_group', 'linktext05' );
    register_setting( 'hpblogposts_settings_options_group', 'linkalt05' );
    register_setting( 'hpblogposts_settings_options_group', 'linkid06' );
    register_setting( 'hpblogposts_settings_options_group', 'linktext06' );
    register_setting( 'hpblogposts_settings_options_group', 'linkalt06' );
}
```

For each "group" of settings register_settings is called 3 times.
I was trying to make it easier:

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'hpblogposts_register_settings' );
function csHpBlogPostsSimplyRegisterSettings($id) {
    register_setting( 'hpblogposts_settings_options_group', 'linkid'+$id );
    register_setting( 'hpblogposts_settings_options_group', 'linktext'+$id );
    register_setting( 'hpblogposts_settings_options_group', 'linkalt'+$id );
}
function hpblogposts_register_settings() {
    csHpBlogPostsSimplyRegisterSettings('01');
    csHpBlogPostsSimplyRegisterSettings('02');
    csHpBlogPostsSimplyRegisterSettings('03');
    csHpBlogPostsSimplyRegisterSettings('04');
    csHpBlogPostsSimplyRegisterSettings('05');
    csHpBlogPostsSimplyRegisterSettings('06');
}
```

but it doesnt work this way (values are not saved).

Any idea where I have made a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one, when you're concatenating strings you should [use a dot, not a plus](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php):

```
register_setting( 'hpblogposts_settings_options_group', 'linkalt' . $id );
```